# Problems in session.connect() in a method that does SFTP upload

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, jsch

I have a class that uploads a file by SFTP. It uses private key-public keyy pair SSH for authentication. Below is method that uploads the file. I am writing a test method for it. When I call this method from the test class, it fails at session.connect and no line of code gets executed after that.

Method that uploads the file by SFTP:

```
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(fileName));){
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = jsch.getSession(sftpUser, sftpHost, sftpPort);
    if(sshKey.isEmpty()) {
        session.setPassword(sftpPass);
    } else {
        jsch.addIdentity(sftpHost, sshKey.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII), null, null);
    }
    java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    config.put("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey,keyboard-interactive,password");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    log.info("Host connected.");
    Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
    channel.connect();
    log.info("sftp channel opened and connected.");
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
    channelSftp.cd(sftpWorkingFolder);
    channelSftp.put(fileInputStream, new File(fileName).getName());
    channel.disconnect();
    session.disconnect();
} catch (JSchException | SftpException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Below is the Test Method:

```
@Mock
private JSch jSch;
@Mock
FileInputStream fileInputStream;
@Mock
File file;
@Mock
private Session session;
@Mock
private Channel channel;
@Mock
private ChannelSftp channelSftp;
@Mock
private Properties properties;
@Test
public void testSend() throws Exception {
    PowerMockito.whenNew(JSch.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(jSch);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(Properties.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(properties);
    PowerMockito.whenNew(FileInputStream.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(fileInputStream);
    when(jSch.getSession(any(String.class), any(String.class), anyInt())).thenReturn(session);
    doNothing().when(session).connect();
    when(session.openChannel("sftp")).thenReturn(channel);
    doNothing().when(channel).connect();
    doNothing().when(channelSftp).cd(any(String.class));
    FileUtil.send("src/test/resources/testFile.txt","abc",22,"admin","pass","fold", StringUtils.EMPTY);
}
```

This is the exception I get:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: It is hard so see, what you are trying to test, because you do not have any assertions. In the end, the only thing you are interested in is, that the given file is passed to the channelftp.put(). You dont have to test jsch itself, as it is a third party library. I suggest that you first refactor your code, so that is is testable, what you want to test, i.e. make session a parameter of your send method.

Comment: it seems, you mocked session is not used correctly, as the real implementation throws the exception